# php/mysql user login form - stuck

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

evening folks,
been working through my first login script tonight and have hit a brick wall.

I have a script that is sending new users to the db with md5 hash'd passwords, but I'm not having any luck with the authenticating and logging in part, any help greatly appreciated.

Code is below;

```
<?php
//open the session
session_start();
$sqltable="users";
$pagetitle="User Login";
$menu="no";

require 'inc/dbvars.php';
require 'inc/dafunc.php';

//check to see if someone has pressed the login button
    if(isset($_POST['login']))
    {

//connect to the database
    try {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$sqlhost;dbname=$sqldb", $sqluser, $sqlpass);
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
    catch(PDOException $e)
        {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        }

//fetch username and password from form
    $user=$_POST['user'];
    $pass=md5($_POST['pass']);  
//query database and check users's creds
    $query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM $sqltable WHERE username = $user AND password = $pass"); // carefull with your column name which you declare in the tabel

    $query->execute();


     $_SESSION['username']=$user;
     $_SESSION['userlevel']=$row['level'];
//store login data and time in database
    $datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

 //   $query = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE ' . $sqltable . ' SET lastlogin =? WHERE user = ?");
 //   $data = array($datetime, $user);
 //   $query->execute($data);
 // right now you shouldn't perform the update query . and you should use primary key column in where caulse in update query
//if everything is correct, this should redirect the user to the confirm page   
    header("location:search.php");
}

//if the shit has hit the fan, deny deny deny
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}

//login was sucessful, build rest of page
require 'inc/header.php';
?>
<div class="tableForm">
<form name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo "$self"; ?>">
  <p align="center">Username: 
    <input type="text" name="user" id="user" placeholder="username">
</p>
  <p align="center">Password: 
    <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" placeholder="password">
</p>
  <p align="center">
    <input type="submit" name="Login" id="Login" value="Login">
    <input type="reset" name="Reset" id="Reset" value="Reset">
  </p>
  <p align="center">
    <input type="submit" name="forgotpass" id="forgotpass" value="Forgot your password?">
  </p>
</form>
</div>
<?php include 'inc/footer.php'; ?>
```

Comment: When they try to login, what happens? What is going wrong exactly? Also, I see a call to mysql_num_rows in there. I'd take that out.

Comment: You're mixing MySQL APIs and they do **not** mix. Use `rowCount()`

Comment: Side note: using md5 for hashing passwords is really horrible. Use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: *"but I'm not having any luck with the authenticating and logging in part"* - **Call it a "blessing in disguise".** Use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: nothing happens, no errors, no redirection to the confirmation page, nothing! I'm stuck as to where to go from here...

Comment: `SELECT FROM users` should be `SELECT something FROM users`

Comment: I remember having a similar issue, and it was because my password field in my database was accepting only a record of 25 characters. The md5 function returns a 32 character hexadecimal number. Make sure your database field is big enough, or else it gets truncated and you will not get a match

Answer (score 0):

this:

```
//query database and check users's creds
     $query = $dbh->prepare('SELECT FROM users WHERE user =?, pass =?');
```

should be this:

```
//query database and check users's creds
    $query = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user =? AND pass =?');
```

Comment: thanks, have changed this, but still no further along than before.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
  <?php
session_start();
$sqlhost = "localhost";
$sqldb = "dbname";
$sqltable="users";
$sqlpass = "";

$pagetitle="User Login";
$menu="no";

require 'inc/dbvars.php';
require 'inc/dafunc.php';

//check to see if someone has pressed the login button
    if(isset($_POST['login']))
    {

//connect to the database
    try {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$sqlhost;dbname=$sqldb", $sqluser, $sqlpass);
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
    catch(PDOException $e)
        {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        }

//fetch username and password from form
    $user=$_POST['user'];
    $pass=md5($_POST['pass']);  
//query database and check users's creds
    $query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT FROM users WHERE username = $user AND password = $pass"); // carefull with your column name which you declare in the tabel

    $query->execute();


     $_SESSION['username']=$user;
     $_SESSION['userlevel']=$row['level'];
//store login data and time in database
    $datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

 //   $query = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE ' . $sqltable . ' SET lastlogin =? WHERE user = ?");
 //   $data = array($datetime, $user);
 //   $query->execute($data);
 // right now you shouldn't perform the update query . and you should use primary key column in where caulse in update query
//if everything is correct, this should redirect the user to the confirm page   
    header("location:search.php");
}

//if the shit has hit the fan, deny deny deny
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}

//login was sucessful, build rest of page
require 'inc/header.php';
?>
<div class="tableForm">
<form name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo "$self"; ?>">
  <p align="center">Username: 
    <input type="text" name="user" id="user" placeholder="username">
</p>
  <p align="center">Password: 
    <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" placeholder="password">
</p>
  <p align="center">
    <input type="submit" name="Login" id="Login" value="Login">
    <input type="reset" name="Reset" id="Reset" value="Reset">
  </p>
  <p align="center">
    <input type="submit" name="forgotpass" id="forgotpass" value="Forgot your password?">
  </p>
</form>
</div>
<?php include 'inc/footer.php'; ?>
```

Comment: made a few small changes (have updated code in question) and I'm not getting the "incorrect username or password" error for everything

Comment: remmovw this line
//session should be placed on the top of the page
and check with your table data and column for "incorrect username or password"